# Adf - Convert RichInputDate to Date object

Tags: oracle-adf

I'm using af:inputDate in my form.

in my backing bean i'm trying to get the value as Date object.

```
public RichInputDate getFromDate() {
return fromDate;
}

public void convert(){
Date fromDt = (Date)this.getFromDate().getValue(); 
}
```

but I get this error:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date
any idea?
is there a simple way to get the value as Date object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is:
http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-conversion/StringToDate.shtml

It's also safer to use this

```
<af:convertDateTime pattern="yyyy/M/d" secondaryPattern="d/M/yyyy" />
```

inside your input component, so you are sure that it is using the right pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about ADF, having:

```
private RichInputDate invoiceDate;
```

We can just do:

```
String s2 = invoiceDate.getValue().toString();
```

In order to get the date in string format. That will help you to get it in String format, then you can transform it to a Date object.

Regards,

Comment: there's no need to add: toString() here since the problem is that the getValue() returns a String, instead of a Date ...